Cron stops triggering jobs across entire Jenkins instance
It's happened a couple of times in the last few months, that on one of our Jenkins instances, all jobs that are run by cron stop being triggered. Restarting the Jenkins instance fixes it so that cron works again for all jobs. But we don't want it to keep happening that cron stops working.
I looked in the Jenkins error log and don't see anything relevant.
I'm running Jenkins 2.440.3. I can't find anyone else mentioning this issue. Perhaps this is a new bug that hasn't yet been reported. Has anyone experienced this or knows what the cause is?
